# Not able to load third party class in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, solr, solarium

My main problem is, that i dont have access to Solarium (a third party libary) in my symfony2-project and I do not understand why.
I have a symfony2 application and want to write my own Solr connector. Therefore I want to use Solarium. (IMPORTANT: I dont want to use other bundles for this)

First I installed it via composer

```
"require": {
        //...
        "solarium/solarium": "3.3.0.x-dev"
    }
```

Then i called:

```
php composer.phar install

php composer.phar update
```

Second i created a new directory for my connector in my bundle:

/src/COMPANY/ThatIsMyBundle/SolrSearch/

In this directory is my class SolrConnector.php

```
namespace COMPANY\ThatIsMyBundle\SolrSearch;

use Solarium\Client;
//use Solarium\Core\Client;

class SolrConnector {
        private $solr_client;
        function __construct($settings)
        {
            $solr_config = array(
                'endpoint' => array(
                    'protokolldb' => array(
                        'host' => $settings['solrHost'],
                        'port' => $settings['solrPort'],
                        'path' => $settings['path'],
                        'core' => $settings['core'],
                        'timeout' => $settings['timeout']
                    )
                )
            );
            $this->solr_client = new Client($solr_config);
        }

         /**
         * Check if Solr is on.
         */
       function executePing() {
            $ping = $this->solr_client->createPing();
            try {
                $this->solr_client->ping($ping);
                echo "Solr is fine.\n";
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                echo "Solr is unaccessible. Look up whats wrong with Solr and restart this script.\n ".$e->getMessage();
            }
        }

    }
```

I got this error message from symfony:

> Attempted to load class "Client" from namespace "Solarium" in "(my
>   specific path to the project)/SolrSearch/SolrConnector.php line 32."
>   Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?

What i have to do to use Solarium in my Symfony2 Bundle?
I think it is a namespace/use/require problem.
I googled it for hours... with no solution.

Things i tried:

adding

```
require('../vendor/autoload.php);
```

same error.

Comment: Did you add the Bundle in your `AppKernel` class?

Comment: @KhorneHoly the Bundle is fine. I generate with the symfony2 command generate:bundle

Comment: Look at vendor directory. Is Solarium present? If not, try to run `composer update` instead of `install`.

Comment: @kbarborak its present.

Comment: Could you paste Client file into solarium bundle? (remember to inclued the path as a comment, thank you)

Comment: You need to add your bundle autoload_namespaces in vendor/composore

Comment: @DonCallisto solarium isnt a bundle and I dont prefer to paste my code into foreign packages which i dont own. Thematically does my code not belong to solarium.

Comment: No, sorry, I haven't expressed myself in a proper way. My statement should have been: "Could you paste HERE the "Client" file that is into Solarium bundle" (or folder, or whatever)?

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
php composer.phar install
```

it only install packages stored in composer.lock

You need to run

```
php composer.phar update
```

to install new packages. It also clear and warm up symfony cache and autoloader

Comment: solarium is installed well. it is in my vendor directory. I think the solution has to do with the namespace. i would get other errors if solarium isnt installed well